# Flutter Render package - Installation Error - Ffmpeg

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to install the Render package but I'm getting this error:

```
"The 'Pods-Runner' target has frameworks with conflicting names: ffmpegkit.xcframework, libavcodec.xcframework, libavdevice.xcframework, libavfilter.xcframework, libavformat.xcframework, libavutil.xcframework, libswresample.xcframework, and libswscale.xcframework."
```

Everything installs perfectly when I remove Render from my dependencies